# How to make a pendrive snapshot

Tags: backup, usb-drive, dd, clone

I am building a NAS server with Ubuntu Server 12.04 on an old laptop and am very happy with it. The OS is installed on a 8Gb pendrive (the swap partition and grub are also installed on it).

I did a 'backup' using:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/mnt/nas-disk/backups/ubuntu-nas-server/pendrive.iso bs=4M
```

I worked perfectly, in fact I made a mistake and overwrited the pendrive with garbage and I was able to restore all with:

```
dd if=/mnt/nas-disk/backups/ubuntu-nas-server/pendrive.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

However, I have another pendrive with no exactly the same capacity (it is a 8GB pendrive but has 7.9 more or less). When I executed the previous command and tried to boot using the new drive it did not work at all.

The dd command let me know that it was not able to copy all the file in the new device.

I need a way to be able to 'clone' my pendrive in case it fails. Is the any way to do that?

Comment: did you set the flags properly for new drive?

Comment: @AdityaPatil what flags?

Comment: There are following flags on every device/partition:- **boot, diag, hidden, lba, lvm, palo, prep and raid.** You need to enable the boot flag(i.e set it to 1).I have done this the GUI way.I'll try to find the CLI way.

Comment: @AdityaPatil, I am using the CLI way. Given I use the dd command, do I need to set those flags?

Comment: Yes, without the **boot** flag set, the bios won't be able to boot the drive.Software like **unetbootin** do it automatically.But as you are copying the drive, you'll have to go it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For restoring: you could try to:

1. make the (new) partitions on your pendrive (swap and ext3/ext4) using `fdisk /dev/sda` for example
2. mount the new created partition (`mkdir /mnt/tmp1 && mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/tmp1/`)
3. [Mount the data-partition from your .iso/.img](https://serverfault.com/questions/81591/mount-dd-image-with-multiple-partitions) (`mkdir /mnt/tmp2/ && kpartx -a imagefile.img && mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/ -o loop,ro` )
4. copy the data from mounted image to the new data-partition (`cp /mnt/tmp2 /mnt/tmp1 -r` )
5. Unmount the image (`kpartx -d imagefile.img`)
6. Install grub to the MBR of the usbstick  (`grub-install /dev/sda`) (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html)

*These are just example commands. Make them fit to your needs!*

For backing up, you could try to just backup the data-partition (/dev/sda1 for example), it will make it easier to extract the data to anywhere, and not just a complete suitable USBstick

Comment: Guys, calm down a bit. According to [handling link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) this *is* an answer, although not a perfect one.